# What should be imported to create a list?

Tags: java, list, import

I attempted creating a list:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

I compiled it and it said it needed something to import.
I tried `import java.util.Collection;`
But that doesn't do anything.

I tried `java.util.List` but all the error messages gave me the impression that it's kinda risky.

Here's my code so you can understand my dilemma, which is a mod of [this code](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/13flow/Factors.java.html):

```
// purpose: remodify original program such that it will not print duplicate factors. added lines are marked by //t

import java.util.Collection; //???????????????? //t
public class Factors
{
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        // command-line argument
        long n = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        List list = new ArrayList(); //potato, attempt to create a list so that I can later modify the list such that it will delete dupes right before printing
        System.out.print("The prime factorization of " + n + " is: ");

        // for each potential factor i
        for (long i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {

            // if i is a factor of N, repeatedly divide it out
            while (n % i == 0) {
                System.out.print(i + " "); 
                n = n / i;
            }
            list.add(n);
        }

        Set set = new HashSet(list); //t, I read somewhere that this will clear the dupes
        // if biggest factor occurs only once, n > 1
        if (n > 1){ 
            System.out.println(set); //t, i assume it will do as expected, but right now the import error is stopping me

        }
        else       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

being new to java, I did not know what the hell I was doing. Going back on this question, I believe all I had to do was `import java.util.ArrayList;` and it would work as I needed. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: You could just use `import java.util.*`

Comment: @Mad java.util.List is abstract, cannot be instantiated

Comment: @RegisteredUser That's an interface. Not Abstract. And There is no relation to your's and Mad-programmers comment.

Comment: All those javadocs just out there waiting to be read, but no, post on S.O. first...

Comment: @John3136 I attempted reading the oracle docs for lists but it makes absolutely no sense. the official python docs were a lot easier to understand :/

Comment: @RegisteredUser But the OP never tries to instantiate an instance of `List`, they are using `ArrayList` and polymorphism

Comment: @RegisteredUser Why not import `ArrayList` along with `List`? Too difficult??

Comment: @BalwinderSingh And `List`.  The OP needs to import `List`, `ArrayList`, `Set` and `HashSet` or just `java.util.*`

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats true. I assumed he will figure out the rest :)

Comment: @Bal @Mad I have attempted adding `java.util.ArrayList` and ` java.util.List`  but it says it uses unsafe operations. I added `package collections;` in the beginning to see what would happen, and it would get auto-deleted

Comment: @RegisteredUser `import`, `import`, `import`.  The likely reason you're getting `unsafe operations` warnings is not because of how you imported the classes, but because of they way you are using the classes (probably without generics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

List<data type> var = new ArrayList<data type>();
```

Example `List<String> var = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: This is what I saw in one of the tutorials. trying now.

Comment: You need to import every class and interface you are using in your code.So as you are using LIst and ArrayList, you need to have imports for both.

Comment: It works, thanks! how can I remove duplicates from a list? so that when it prints out, it would be 2,3,4 instead of 2,2,3,3,4?

Comment: @RegisteredUser Use a `Set`

Comment: `Set<Long> set=new HashSet<>(list);` now how do I print this new list? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @RegisteredUser Like you would any list, simply use an enhanced for-loop

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am unsure how to implement the loop into this. I am new to Java.

Comment: `for (String value : set)` - Have a look at [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

You will want to import:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

This is because you are using both the general implementation of List and also using the class ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather hard to discover exactly what you are trying to do, but here is some shallow surface help:

1. You need to delete the import for collections and add:
     import java.util,ArrayList;
   and one of:

   import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.LinkedList;
     import java.util.Vector;
     import java.util.Stack;
   or, if the list is to be displayable:
     import java.awt.List;  or
     import java.swing.JList;
2. For all of them, including Set and HashSet, you need to specify
   the type of entries which will be added to the object, for example,
   judging from your text: 
     ArrayList alist = new Arraylist();
     List longlist = new List();
     longlist = alist;
   although the above may be nonsense in terms of your end goals, it is a
   valid translation of your statement: 
     List list = new ArrayList();

I wish I could help more, but based upon the information you supplied,
the above is safe and reasonable in terms of Java requirements.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, you generally don't add more than one answer to a question. Please consolidate your answers all into a single answer. I'm referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/32941322/456814 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/32941153/456814. You can edit your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the garbled text. Here is a better one:
It is rather hard to discover exactly what you are trying to do, but here is some shallow surface help:

1. You need to delete the import for collections and add:

   > import java.util,ArrayList; and one of:

   ```
   -import java.util.ArrayList; 
   -import java.util.LinkedList; 
   -import java.util.Vector; 
   -import java.util.Stack;
   ```

   > or, if the list is to be displayable:

   ```
   -import java.awt.List; or 
   -import java.swing.JList;
   ```
2. For all of them, including Set and HashSet, you need to specify the type of entries which will be added to the object, for example, judging from your text:

   ```
   ArrayList alist = new Arraylist(); 
   List longlist = new List(); 
   longlist = alist;
   ```

Although the above may be nonsense in terms of your end goals, it is a valid translation of your statement: List list = new ArrayList();

I wish I could help more, but based upon the information you supplied, the above is safe and reasonable in terms of Java requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry again, the entry system ate up the type indicators, but finally here they are: It is rather hard to discover exactly what you are trying to do, but here is some shallow surface help:

1. You need to delete the import for collections and add:

> ```
>    import java.util,ArrayList;
> ```
>
> and one of:

- List item  import java.util.ArrayList;
- List item  import java.util.LinkedList;
- List item  import java.util.Vector;
- List item  import java.util.Stack;

or, if the list is to be displayable:

- List item  import java.awt.List; or
- List item  import java.swing.JList;

  2. For all of them, including **Set** and **HashSet**, you need to specify the type of entries which will be added to the object, for example, judging from your text:

> Blockquote

```
ArrayList<long> alist = new Arraylist<long>(); 
List<long> longlist = new List<long>(); 
longlist = alist;
```

> Blockquote

Although the above may be nonsense in terms of your end goals, it is a valid translation of your statement: List list = new ArrayList();

I wish I could help more, but based upon the information you supplied, the above is safe and reasonable in terms of Java requirements.

Comment: I have a subquestion after this original problem was solved. It's in the comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32940877/4040096) I need to implement a for loop but I don't know how.